# Entity Framework Dynamic DbSet for all entities

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, dynamic-data, auto-generate

I have a database mapped with Entity Framework,

I need to implement a generic method for getting a a list of items based on a parameter that I pass:

```cs
getGenericList("product"); // returns the list of products
getGenericList("customer"); // returns the list of customers
```

I need to dynamically get the `dbSet`.  My method is implemented like this:

```cs
public static List<object> getGenericList(string entityType)
    {
        List<object> myDynamicList = new List<object>();
        using (cduContext db = new cduContext())
        {
            DbSet dbSet = db.getDBSet(entityType);
            var myDynamicList = dbSet.Select(p => p).ToList();
        }
        return new List<object>();
    }
```

my `dbSets` are auto-generated by EF code first :

```cs
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DbSet<Custommer> Custommers { get; set; }
```

my `getDBSet(entityType)` method is implemented in the context, like this:

```cs
public DbSet<T> getDBSet<T>(string entityName) where T : class
    {
        switch (entityName)
        {

            case "product":
                return Products;

            case "custommer":
                return Custommers;
```

I then got this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'

Any Idea please !?

N.B. , the method `Set()` of the `dbContext` is not OK; the type should be explicitly given ...

Comment: You might want to correct the spelling of "custommer" -> "customer" in your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the `switch`, you can lookup the Type by its assembly-qualified name, then get the `DbSet` from that.  The DbSet retrieved this way is not generic<>, so the operations you can perform are more limited.

You can get the assembly-qualified name by using a known entity type (e.g. `Product`), getting its assembly-qualified name, then replacing "Product" with the desired name to get the Type.

This example is simplified from a [Breeze](http://breeze.github.io/) app, in which certain lookup entities could be requested by name from the client.

```cs
public async Task<List<object>> GetGenericList(string entityType)
{
  using (var context = new MyContext())
  {
    var aqtemp = typeof(Product).AssemblyQualifiedName; // template for qualified name

    var aqname = aqtemp.Replace("Product", entityType); // qualified name for entityType

    var type = Type.GetType(aqname, true, true);      // Type for entityType

    var list = await context.Set(type).ToListAsync(); // query the entities
    return list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's better to stay away from strings as types and mapping them to real types; that's a code smell. Instead, use the types themselves. Either way, let's refactor your code that uses the `getGenericList()` method to use generics. If you can't get away from strings, do the mapping in the code that calls `getGenericList()` as opposed to mapping inside that method, since we're following the pattern you've set forth.

Also note that in your original `getGenericList()` you're always returning an empty list, as opposed to the list you obtained via EF. You're also using 2 different `myDynamicList` variables; the outer one is masked by the one in the scope of the `using` statement which is why you don't get a compiler error. Once the `using` goes out of scope, the inner `myDynamicList` goes out of scope too. I've addressed that here.

```cs
public static List<T> getGenericList<T>()
{
    List<T> myDynamicList;

    using (cduContext db = new cduContext())
    {
        // consider using exception handling here as GetDbSet might get an invalid type
        DbSet dbSet = db.GetDbSet<T>();
        myDynamicList = dbSet.Select(p => p).ToList();
    }

    if (myDynamicList != null && myDynamicList.Count() > 0)
    {
        return myDynamicList;
    }
    return new List<T>();
}

// in your context class
public DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>() where T : class
{
    return this.Set<T>();
}

// this is the code that calls getGenericList(); put this inside a function somewhere. 
// entityName holds a string value, set previously
switch(entityName.ToLower()) // making entityName case insensitive
{
    case "product":
        return getGenericList<Product>();

    case "customer":
        return getGenericList<Customer>();
}
```

Hopefully you won't have too many entity types that you want to map, or you'll end up with a huge `switch` statement. Again, if you're using a `switch` statement, in general it's probably an indication that you need to re-think your approach.